# Read name of Package attribute and rename the current file with name of the package

Tags: python, shell

We have a requirement in python, where we have 50 txt files as below in a folder; what we need here is take out the name(com.paytm.mShop.android.install) of the package attribute and rename the file (ex:Paytm.txt) to packageName.txt(com.paytm.mShop.android.install.txt) for all the files in the given folder

```
Example : Paytm.txt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.paytm.android.install">
   .
   .
   ..
</manifest>
```

I appreciate  all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches you could take to extract the package name:

1. Parse the file as an XML file, and then extract the package name:

   ```
   def extract_package_name(filename):
       tree = ET.parse('Paytm.txt')
       root = tree.getroot()
       return root.attrib["package"]
   ```
2. Use regular expressions

   ```
   def extract_package_name(filename):
       with open(filename, 'r') as manifest_file:
           for line in manifest_file:
               mo = re.match('pattern="(.*)">', line)
               if mo:
                   return mo.group(1)
   ```

Renaming the file should be easy:

```
def rename_file(file):
    package_name = extract_package_name(file)
    os.rename(file, package_name + ".txt")
```